Feasibility of Creating a Ribbon Button Add-in for OneNote Desktop with Custom UI (C#)
I'm exploring the feasibility of implementing the following use case in OneNote Desktop (M365 2410) and would appreciate your insights. Unfortunately, I couldn't find sufficient information in the official documentation or other resources online.
Use Case Overview:

The user types text into OneNote.
They click a custom ribbon button.
Clicking the button opens a custom UI (e.g., WPF or WinForms).
This UI reads the content from the current notebook and allows
additional input.
The data (from both OneNote and the custom UI) is sent to an
external web service.

Challenges:

From my research, it seems there's no dedicated VSTO project type for
OneNote.
I attempted to use IRibbonExtensibility and register my DLL via COM
(regasm), but these efforts were unsuccessful.
The official docs suggest a JavaScript-based approach, which appears
to target OneNote Online, but my focus is exclusively on the OneNote
Desktop application.
The only related sample code I’ve found is outdated (circa 2010).

Is it possible to create this type of extension for OneNote Desktop using a "heavy client" approach with C#?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#how-are-office-add-ins-different-from-com-and-vsto-add-ins

@HansPassant Sounds clear, however, I mentioned that I need WPF or WinForm because I need to use some DLL... Anyway, are you confirming that VSTO/COM are not possible anymore with OneNote ? About AddIns, I cannot find any doc mentioning how to deal with Office AddIns (HTML/JS) for Desktop app. Each time they mention to connect to Office online. Any idea on that ?

No, you have to do this in Javascript.  Preventing programmers from injecting a large language runtime with icky dependencies and versioning headaches (like the .NET CLR) is surely intentional..

@HansPassant These icky methods that you describe are still relevant for other Office tools, such as Word, via VSTO, and even widely used. There are some use cases that can only be done in a heavy client. Ok for Javascript, no worries with it, but again, do you have any idea where to start to apply it to the Desktop version. I can't find any source on this.
